# a+b+c = 10 all possible solutions

Tags: permutations, combinations

Consider three integers $a, b, c \in \{0, 1, ... , 10\}$. I know that there are ${12 \choose 2}$ possible combinations for which $a + b + c = 10$. However, I am looking for the number of solutions for which none of the integers are repeated. For instance, the solution $1, 2, 7$ is a valid combination, but $3, 3, 4$ is not. How many valid combinations are there?

Comment: Are you assuming that $a,b,c\in \{0,1,\ldots ,9 \}$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde if it doesn't, the set of solutions is infinite.

Comment: What are the constraints on $a,b,c$ besides that $a,b,c$ shouldn't repeat? Without additional constraints, there are infinitely many such possibilities.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder No, that is wrong. Let $a,b,c\in \{ -1,0,1,\ldots ,7\}$. Then the set of solutions is not infinite.

Comment: Who said they are in the range $[-1,7]$? Did the OP mention it and I have missed that?

Comment: a,b,c ∈ N. All are positive integrals

Comment: Who said that the range is $[0,9]$ in the question? In the question nothing is said, in fact - hence my question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde the OP answered. Any $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yes, **after** my question the OP answered. And you are wrong, not any $a,b,c$ in natural numbers.

Comment: It's just a badly asked question, no need to argue here :)

Comment: Sorry frds i'm new to stack so if you guys need more detail than plz tell me

Comment: @DietrichBurde as *Pawel* said, no need to argue here. I just reproduced what the OP stated : *a,b,c ∈ N. All are positive **integrals***. That's even worse! :/

Comment: Dear Dharmik. In the future you should say exactly in the question what your assumptions are. This is not clear otherwise.

Comment: Do you count $2,3,4$ and $3,2,4$ as different combinations?

Comment: Yes both are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count them.  The minimum number can't be 3 or more because $3+4+5>10$.  If the minimum is $0$ you have four choices for the other two digits, for a minimum of $1$ you have three more but for a minimum of $2$ You have just  $2+3+5$.  Your answer is either $8$ or $48$ depending on whether you separately count different orderings for a given set of three digits.

Comment: Hi, Oscar Lanzi I'm not a mathematician so can you tell me why we are dividing 48 by 6 if i do not consider order.

Comment: If you consider three elements $A$, $B$ and $C$, there are six ways to order them: $ABC,$ $ACB,$ $BAC,$ $BCA,$ $CAB$ and $CBA$. In general, there are $n! = n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) \times ... \times 2 \times 1$ ways to order $n$ elements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 5):

We must divide 10 units among three integers, and this can indeed happen in ${12 \choose 2}$ ways. There are only six options for repeating numbers ($0-5$), since $2 \cdot 6 \gt 10$. As such, the number of solutions without repeating numbers equals:

$${12 \choose 2} - {3 \choose 2} \cdot 6 = 48$$

Comment: Thanks @jvdhooft for your answer this is what i want.

Comment: You are welcome, and welcome to MathSE. If this or any other answer helped you, please consider upvoting/accepting.

Comment: I'm sorry this is my first day so how can i upvote?

Comment: You can give all relevant answers an upvote by clicking on the upwards arrow to the left of the question, and you can accept the most relevant answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: I was going to write that we also have to exclude solutions in which one of the numbers is $10,$ but that set of solutions conveniently turns out to be a subset of the solutions forbidden due to repetition.

Comment: @jvdhooft Thank you for your correction in the question :)

Comment: @DavidK The OP stated that the number of combinations equals ${12 \choose 2}$, but this is only true if the integers are also allowed to equal $10$. I edited the question to account for this. Indeed, this is one of the cases which is forbidden due to repetition.

Comment: @jvdhooft What changes should i make for a,b,c∈ N. I just want to know. So if i encounter this type of question than i can do it by my self.

Comment: @DharmikGadhiya The result is exactly the same for $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$. If $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$, there would be an infinite amount of possible solutions.

Comment: @jvdhooft Good point, the question was self-contradictory as initially stated. But it's OK since your edit.

Comment: Now, another modification if i want to find all the solution where a,b,c∈Na,b,c∈N and a <= 6, b <= 6, c <= 6. How can i solve it?

Comment: @DharmikGadhiya In this case, only the following combinations are valid: $\{0, 4, 6\}$, $\{1, 3, 6\}$, $\{1, 4, 5\}$ and $\{2, 3, 5\}$. As such, there are $4 \times 3! = 24$ possible combinations.

Comment: yes that's right but how to implement it. Is there any formula?